Is a composition $\phi(t,x(t))$ of a $C^{1}$ function $\phi(t,x)$ with a Lipschitz function $x(t)$ a Lipschitz function?
I'm reading a book about optimal control theory, but I don't understand an argument.
Take any Lipschitz continuous arc $x \colon [S,T] \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$. It's true that $t\mapsto \phi(t,x(t))$ is a Lipschitz continuous function, where $\phi\colon\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^{1}
$ function?

All what you need to prove the fact:
Finite increment theorem applied to $\phi\colon\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ together with the fact that $x \colon [S,T] \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a Lipschitz function.
You can try to write your attempt here, then somebody will check the correctness of it.

$\rm{id}$ is  Lipschitz. If $y,x$ are Lipschitz, so is $(y,x)$. If $\phi,z$ are Lipschitz, so is $\phi\circ z$. If $\phi$ is $C^1$ then it is Lipschitz on every bounded set.
